# Mysql Different order by result between inner join query and exists query

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables in the database

1. User table
   has columns (name, name_ar, ...)
2. User Profile table
   has columns (user_id, office_id, address, mobile, ...)

the relationship between the two tables is one to one relation

Now, I'm trying to filter users by their office and order them by name_ar.
I tried two different queries to do this and I expect the same result from the two queries but the result is different in order.

```
SELECT
    `id`, `name_ar`
FROM
    `users`
WHERE EXISTS
    (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        `user_profiles`
    WHERE
        `users`.`id` = `user_profiles`.`user_id` AND `office_id` = 1
) AND(
    `group` = "doctor" AND `state` = "active"
) AND `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
ORDER BY
    `name_ar` IS NULL, `name_ar` ASC
```

[image: exists query result]

```
SELECT
    `u`.`id`,
    `name_ar`
FROM
    `users` u
INNER JOIN `user_profiles` up ON
    `u`.`id` = `up`.`user_id`
WHERE
    `group` = "doctor" AND `state` = "active" AND `up`.`office_id` = 1
ORDER BY
    `name_ar` IS NULL, `name_ar` ASC
```

[image: inner join query result]

the two results do not have the same order from the beginning of appearing null value in name_ar column (from the fifth row exactly the order is different between the two results), Can any explain for me why is this happens? Is it because of null values or another reason?

Comment: It is because of NULL value.. having all those NULLs then ordering by it is similar to doing random ordering..

Answer (score 1):

The 1st condition of the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
`name_ar` IS NULL
```

sends all `null`s to the end of the results.

The 2nd:

```
`name_ar` ASC
```

sorts the non `null` names alphabetically but when it comes to the `null` names at the end there is not any defined order for them.

What you can do is add another final condition, like:

```
`id` ASC
```

so you have all the `null`s (and duplicate names if they exist) sorted by `id`:

```
ORDER BY `name_ar` IS NULL, `name_ar`, `id`
```